# Surveyee but not Stackoverflower

Tags: discussion, survey

One of the most surprising results from the developer survey *(to me)* was [21.2% of participants don't have a Stackoverflow account](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#community-rep). Is there a breakdown of where these people came from? I'm guessing from other StackExchange sites. Was there a push for respondents from non-StackExchange communities?

Comment: I'd guess that most don't have an account on any SE site.

Comment: Anonymous users? Way more of them than there are registered users.

Comment: I think you were shown the survey link regardless whether you were logged in to Stack Overflow or not, so the users are likely to have come from there.

Comment: You don't need a Stack Overflow user account to be a Stack Overflow user. For a lot of people who search and end up here regularly, they probably never need to ask a new question or feel compelled to search for ones they can answer.

Comment: Don't believe too much what you read there, other than the number of cups of coffee stats, surveys like this suffer from a major selection bias.  They are skipped by busy people, professionals.  Reading the results, you have to wonder how many of them don't know that their text editor converts a Tab key press into spaces :)